# How do you get a minimal SDL program to compile and link in visual studio 2008 express?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I'm trying to use SDL in C++ with Visual Studio 2008 Express. The following program compiles but does not link:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

The link error is:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

I get this regardless of how or if I link with SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib. Defining `main` as `main()` or `SDL_main()` gives the same error, with or without `extern "C"`.

Edit: I solved this by not including SDL.h in main.cpp - a refactoring I did independent of the problem. A similar solution would be to `#undef main` right before defining the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have VC++ available at the moment, but I have seen this issue several times.

You need to create a Win32 project as opposed to a console project. A Win32 project expects a [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx) function as a program entry point. SDLmain.lib contains this entry point and the SDL_main.h header file has a macro that remaps your main function to SDL_main. This function is called by the entry point in the SDLmain library.

The main function must have the following signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

It is also required to include SDL.h before the declaration of your main function, and you need to link to both SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib.

It looks like you are doing this. **So, my guess is that you have a console project setup.** Therefore, **the linker is looking for a main function to call, but it is getting remapped to SDL_main by the macro SDL_main.h**. So, the linker can't find an entry point and gives up!

Comment: Yes, changing from to a windows application (through Project Properties / Configuration Properties / Linker / System / SubSystem) works. Thanks. (I ended up with a different solution, though)

Answer (score 3):

To me it helped to add the following lines before main():

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#undef main
#endif
```

[German Wikipedia](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/SDL:_Die_erste_SDL-Anwendung) also suggests to add these lines instead:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDLmain.lib")
#endif
```

Though I still had link errors when I tried second solution.

Answer (score 0):

The linker can't find the entry point. Which means your main() function is not recognized as the entry point.

If you have a .def file, remove it.

Also, if you've set up your project to compile with unicode and not as mbcs, you have to use wmain() instead of main().