# Program crashing on exit

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, crash, sdl

Whenever I exit my program it gives me this exception "0xC0000022:  A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights."

It breaks right at the end of a function called _lock_file in _file.c.

After trying to narrow down what the cause of the problem is I found out that it does not crash if I remove all fclose() function calls in my program then cleaning and rebuilding my program. Even if the function itself is never called it will still crash. Obviously this solution is not ideal.

When I tried to use fstream instead it produced a similar crash at the start of the program.

It's also worth mentioning that my program uses SDL.

Edit: Someone requested a minimal example and this is what I cam up with.

main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
/*...*/
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDLmain.lib")
/*...*/
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(false)
        fclose(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

draw.cpp

```
/*...*/
```

If I run this it will crash on exit just like I mentioned above. And yes the draw.cpp is completely commented out, but if I remove it from the project the program will run fine. All other files were removed from the project.

Edit2: In response to karlphillip I decided to double check if it is actually running and it seems that it is actually crashing at the start with this example.

Also it is a Win32 project.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is hard to tell exactly what is causing the problem, but the likely cause is that you are writing to a log file in a destructor of an object but closing the file before the destructor is called.

Comment: After performing a séance and speaking with the spirits on the other side I have been told that your problem is actually on line 42 in the file wtf_you_want_me_to_guess.cpp.

Comment: Sorry, but my program is just too large for me to post the entire thing.

Comment: Can you distill it down to a minimal example that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the same runtime library (Debug DLL, Debug, Release DLL, Release, etc.) for your main program as was used to build the SDL library? That can often (but not always) cause odd problems, and would be my first port of call when getting this sort of odd behaviour at runtime.

(If you get an LNK4098 warning when building, this is what it is trying to tell you, and you really need to fix it properly; the "solution" the text of the warning suggests is anything but.)

Another option is memory corruption. Consider running a debug build, and calling the following on startup:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG)|_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF);
```

This activates more thorough heap checking. (You might have to go and make a cup of tea when your program runs with this switched on, if it allocates lots of stuff while it's running.) If then "crashes" in one of the memory allocation functions -- it's actually an assert, you can't always tell though -- then at some point between that call, and the previous call to a memory management function, something has overwritten some memory it should not have. And you can take it from there, to find out what.

-Edit: "_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG_DF", was probably intended to be "_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG".

Comment: It looks like I had it set to the wrong Runtime Library. It needed to be "Multi-threaded DLL". It works great now.

Answer (score 3):

Having a crash on exit usually means that the heap is corrupted during program execution. Try using a memory checker to find where. Try using _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()

Answer (score 1):

Crashing on exit can also be caused by static variables destructing and accessing objects that have already been cleaned up.

Check you static objects and ensure their destructors are not causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your application is being executed in the first place? Add a debug right after main() is called:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
/*...*/
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDLmain.lib")
/*...*/
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("dbg1\n");

    if(false)
        fclose(NULL);

    printf("dbg2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What kind of project are you creating? Console, Win32 or something else?

I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396183/how-do-you-get-a-minimal-sdl-program-to-compile-and-link-in-visual-studio-2008-ex) very interesting.