# LNK2019 Error in C++ class definition Example needed

Tags: c++, class, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get a minimal SDL program to compile and link in visual studio 2008 express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396183/how-do-you-get-a-minimal-sdl-program-to-compile-and-link-in-visual-studio-2008-e)

So I am new to C++ and need to create a class. I think this has something to do with the implementation of the methods in the Sprite.cpp.

Can someone give me an example of a simple class with properties and a method. Or at least let me know what I am doing wrong?

Error #1

```
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_String_const_iterator<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Compat(class std::_String_const_iterator<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?_Compat@?$_String_const_iterator@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEXABV12@@Z)   D:\GSE\Game with Jon Bye\game\game\main.obj
```

Error #2

```
Error   13  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\GSE\Game with Jon Bye\game\Debug\game.exe    1
```

Sprite.h

```
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Functions.h"

using namespace std;

class Sprite
{
private:
    int PosX;
    int PosY;
    int xDist;
    int yDist;
    string ImagePath;
    SDL_Surface Screen;
    SDL_Surface *temp, *sprite, *screen;

public:
    Sprite(int PosX, int PosY, string ImagePath, SDL_Surface Screen );
    void Sprite::DrawSprite( int x, int y, SDL_Surface *sprite, SDL_Surface *screen )
    {
        //Make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
        SDL_Rect offset;

        //Give the offsets to the rectangle
        offset.x = x;
        offset.y = y;

        //Blit the surface
        SDL_BlitSurface( sprite, NULL, screen, &offset );

        SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    void Sprite::Draw()
    {
        #pragma region Char to String Conversion

        string ImagePath;
        char * writable = new char[ImagePath.size() + 1];
        copy(ImagePath.begin(), ImagePath.end(), writable);
        writable[ImagePath.size()] = '\0';

        #pragma endregion
        temp = SDL_LoadBMP(writable);
        sprite = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
        SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

        // free the string after using it
        delete[] writable;

        DrawSprite(PosX, PosY, sprite, screen);
    }

    void Sprite::Move(int xDist, int yDist)
    {
        PosX += xDist;
        PosY += yDist;
        Draw();
    };
};
```

Sprite.cpp

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite(int posX, int posY, std::string imagePath, SDL_Surface screen) :        PosX(posX), PosY(posY), ImagePath(imagePath), Screen(screen)
{
    void DrawSprite( int x, int y, SDL_Surface *sprite, SDL_Surface *screen );
    void Draw();
    void Move(int xDist, int yDist);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unresolved externals in C++ when using vectors and find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003368/unresolved-externals-in-c-when-using-vectors-and-find)

I was in debug mode and not release mode.

Make sure you set up the linker settings etc in the new Release mode that you have selected and that you are building the Release project.

Answer (score 0):

Ah my buddy Jonathan O! Looks like you took my advice to use SDL after all...

I'm not sure what your error means, but I know that in SDL, you need to put this:

```
#undef main
```

After your:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

Or else it will not work. Why? For some reason SDL defines "main" somewhere, so the linker freaks out when you include "SDL.h", and gets all confused (since main is the entry function).

Perhaps this is the source of your error, although I doubt it, the error message looks like it has something to do with strings...

Also, I don't really get what's going on in your Sprite.CPP file. If you're still new to C++ and looking at how to create classes in C++, you'll find some C++ tutorials here, it's how I started learning C++: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=16

Comment: thanks so much. Ill be back more.